# Nest js after do some change, not star succefully

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I have a project in nestJs, but I do a simple change that add a console.log('') and not start.

For start project I use:
`yarn start:dev`

But project stay in:

```
[Nest] 1772  - 23/03/2023, 7:55:13     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 1772  - 23/03/2023, 7:55:13     LOG [InstanceLoader] CommonModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1772  - 23/03/2023, 7:55:13     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1772  - 23/03/2023, 7:55:13     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1772  - 23/03/2023, 7:55:13     LOG [InstanceLoader] EmailModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1772  - 23/03/2023, 7:55:13     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
```

Comment: are you using windows? please run `npm ls typescript`

Comment: yes I use windows, I run `npm ls typescript`, but stay in ConfigModule dependencies initialized, please what commands I need to run

Comment: run `npm ls typescript` and share us the exact typescript version you're using

Comment: npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
ja@1.21.204 C:\
├─┬ @nestjs/cli@9.3.0
│ ├─┬ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@8.0.0
│ │ └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
│ └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/schematics@9.0.4
│ └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
├─┬ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.56.0
│ └─┬ tsutils@3.21.0
│   └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
├─┬ ts-jest@29.0.0
│ └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
├─┬ ts-loader@9.4.2
│ └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
├─┬ ts-node@10.9.1
│ └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
└── typescript@4.9.5

Comment: ok, so it's typescript 4.9. You could downgrade it to 4.8 or try this out: https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#file-change-detected-loops-endlessly

Answer (score 0):

verify yours.json file

```
    "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
```

must check the

> "start:dev": "nest start --watch"